# Should I use Core Data for a mobile shopping application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, persistence, backend

I'm currently developing a mobile shopping iOS application that connects to a RoR's backend to receive all its data.

Would you recomend core data as a way to store persistent data such as

- Users information + Auth token (to stay logged in)
- Photos of items so they don't have to load from the web every time the view is instantiated / app is quit and re-opened(caching).

  - These photos will be shown in multiple table views & description pages

If you don't recommend using core data. What other options would you say are best for someone in this situation to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would utilize CoreData for your caching. You can easily store your images as NSData objects. For your Auth token, you may want to consider using the keychain. Take a look at the [Keychain Services Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html).

Comment: Thanks i'll give it a try and just found this wrapper to impliment keychains easily. Already have it saving authtoken - [sskeychain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain)

Answer (score 2):

Your bullet points are describing some simple preference-like items and then an image caching scheme. I don't see a reason to use core data or even sql lite. (Core data, incidentally has a steep learning curve.)  You may be better off using NSUserDefaults for the auth token and then implement a file based image caching mechanism. Since the urls are unique, then create a file name by hashing the url. When you fetch the image, generate the hash based file name and see if it's in the file system first, if not fetch it over the net and store it for the next time.

Comment: I agree with the general point; for caching the images, if you design the RoR side well, you can use some built-in IOS caching functionality and get most of it for free: http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/